# RSS parse with PHP gives nothing?

Tags: php, parsing, rss

I am trying to parse a rss-feed with php but it gives me nothing. As you can see I am trying to echo both the $doc and the $itemRSS array and it gives me nothing and the "Success!" for when item 0 in the array is never reached.

I would be thrilled if someone could say "have you thought about [idiotic mistake]?", so please consider me a noob for this question. Thank you!

```
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load('http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=566903fd393811762dc74aadc701badd&_render=rss');
  $arrFeeds = array();
  foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $itemRSS = array ( 
      'guid' => $node->getElementsByTagName('guid')->item(0)->nodeValue
      );
    array_push($arrFeeds, $itemRSS);
  }

    if ($itemRSS[0] != NULL) {

        echo 'Success!';

    }

echo $itemRSS;
echo $doc;
```

And by this I mean that the page is completely blank. No error, nothing.

Update:
Apprently my webhost has allow_url_fopen deactivated, so I have to find another way to do this. *sigh*

Comment: I've always found SimpleXML much easier to use http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, you're doing a couple of things wrong, such as trying to echo arrays and objects. For some reason you're not getting any results in $arrFeeds either, although you should.

A simpler way to do this is change the render method of the feed to JSON: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=566903fd393811762dc74aadc701badd&_render=json

Then you can use json_decode() to get an array of all items:

```
$contents = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=566903fd393811762dc74aadc701badd&_render=json'));
foreach($contents['items'] as $item) {
  // use $item['title'], $item['description'] etc... 
}
```

Note you can only echo strings, ints, etc. not structured data such as arrays or objects.

To make it easier, you can open that URL in your browser and analyze the JSON contents @ http://json.parser.online.fr/ - you'll see how your array is structured then.

JSON is a much easier format to work with IMO.

Edit:

Since file_get_contents() is disabled you can use cURL (which should be installed on most servers, especially with allow_url_fopen disabled):

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried with with json first but couldn't get it to work. I'm used to working with objective-c and php is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: When I use var_dump($contents); I get NULL. Should that happen?

Comment: Nop, that shouldn't happen. Check your error logs, file_get_contents might be disabled for external links.

Comment: You know what it was? My webhost has allow_url_fopen deactivated... have to find another way to do it. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought. Edited answer to add details on how to work around that issue.

Comment: Thank you. And then I put that function before the foreach loop? I can't get that part to work properly :/

Comment: You put that function before the json_decode() part and change file_get_contents() with file_get_contents_curl() :)

Answer (score 0):

Add to the end of your script these lines and check it.

```
var_dump($itemRSS);
var_dump($arrFeeds);
var_dump($doc);
```

The problem is knowing you are not properly display the information.

Comment: That gives me: NULL array(0) { } object(DOMDocument)#1 (0) { }. What does that mean?

Comment: What it means is that you have to review your code to get what you want. What you want to do?

Comment: I want to get the rss feed, compare it to something I have stored to see if there is something new and then do X. :) I would store the GUID in a mySQL database, but that code I could probably work out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with script other than you trying to echo one object and one array, print_r $arrFeeds you can see everything